# Toggling between icon and larger image with transition

Tags: jquery

I want to on-click toggle between an icon sized image and a larger one with a smooth transition between the two. Here is the html:

```
 <head>
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/image_toggle.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="pic_holder">
   <p id="toggle_para"><img id="toggle_image" src="./images/scene1.png"></p>
  </div>
 </body>
```

and the jquery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('img#toggle_image').on('click', function () {
    var origsrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var src = '';
    if (origsrc == './images/icon.png') src = './images/larger_image.png';
    if (origsrc == './images/larger_image.png') src = './images/icon.png';
    jQuery(this).attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

However, while the icon is displayed, on clicking shows only a broken image symbol, not the larger image. On clicking the broken image symbol, the icon is shown. So the script is working to that extent.

I've checked the script with Firebug and the srcs are being switched correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated. As a postcript, how might a smooth transition between the two images be effected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img#toggle_image').on('click', function() {
    var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var src = '';
    origsrc == 'http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/fl_png8/https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' ? src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png' : src = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/fl_png8/https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';//toggle between the src
    
    $(this)
        .fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src);//set src
    })
        .fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic_holder">
  <p id="toggle_para">
    <img id="toggle_image" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/fl_png8/https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $("img#toggle_image").on("click", function(){
    var origsrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    console.log(origsrc)
    var src =""
    if(origsrc == "http://placehold.it/300x200/afa6cc/ffffff&text=icon2"){
      src = "http://placehold.it/200x100/ff66cc/ffffff&text=icon1"
    } 
    else if(origsrc == "http://placehold.it/200x100/ff66cc/ffffff&text=icon1"){
      src = "http://placehold.it/300x200/afa6cc/ffffff&text=icon2"
    } 
    console.log(src)
    $(this).parent("p").fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).children("img").attr("src", src).parent("p").fadeIn()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p id="toggle_para"><img id="toggle_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x100/ff66cc/ffffff&text=icon1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) that switches between 2 states `.on` and `.off`. The CSS properties [`transform`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/), and [`transition`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) were used. The only element is a `div` with [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) and [`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images) which keeps the image on the edges and maintain aspect ratio.

**Snippet**

```js
$('#img').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('off on');
    return false;
});
```

```css
#img {
  width: 256px; height: 256px; background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; cursor:pointer; }
  .off {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 256px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    transform: scale(.50);
  }
  .on {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100vh;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transform: scale(4);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img" class='off'></div>
```